# The name 'Marshal' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#-3.0, directshow.net, marshalling

I got the code below from the bitmapmixer sample (DirectShow.NET) and i tried to reimplement it. The original sample works fine. In my version when I try to compile i get errors.

```
private void AddHandlers()
    {
        // Add handlers for VMR purpose
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint); // for WM_PAINT
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_ResizeMove); // for WM_SIZE
        this.Move += new EventHandler(Form1_ResizeMove); // for WM_MOVE
        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged); // for WM_DISPLAYCHANGE
        handlersAdded = true;
    }

    private void RemoveHandlers()
    {
        // remove handlers when they are no more needed
        handlersAdded = false;
        this.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
        this.Resize -= new EventHandler(Form1_ResizeMove);
        this.Move -= new EventHandler(Form1_ResizeMove);
        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
    }
```

---

---

ERRORs

---

Error   1   The name 'Marshal' does not exist in the current context        Form1.cs
Error   2   The name 'Marshal' does not exist in the current context        Form1.cs
Error   3   The name 'Form1_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context   Form1.cs
Error   4   The name 'Form1_Paint' does not exist in the current context        Form1.cs
Error   5   The name 'Form1_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context   Form1.cs
Error   6   The name 'Form1_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context   Form1.cs
Error   7   The name 'SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged' does not exist in the current context    Form1.cs
Error   10  The name 'Form1_ResizeMove' does not exist in the current context           Form1.cs
Error   11  The name 'SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged' does not exist in the current context    Form1.cs

---

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class is in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace. Do you have an appropriate `using` directive?

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

As for the other errors - do you have those methods in your class? If not, remove the lines which are trying to subscribe event handlers for them...

Answer (score -1):

public static class Marshal is a Member of System.Runtime.InteropServices

you just have to add:

using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
in that .cs file